# How can I get all data from multiple pages from my api?

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios

I am creating a Vue application for my product listing. I am trying to get **all** product information from my api. My api has multiple pages and I am not sure how I can mention that in the url.

```
var app = new Vue({
  'el': '#myapp',
  data: {
    products: "",
    chosenProduct: null
  },
  created: function() {
    axios.get("https://my_api_link/products?page=" + (page || 1) + "&limit=250&access_token=my_access_token", {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      app.products = response.results;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
})
```

I have tried the above but it doesn't work for me. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: So you want to send multiple requests and concat the results from each response?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make multiple calls.

While I would probably not use this approach in lieu of something more complex, I think this may give you an understanding of how to achieve it.

This will get data for a known amount of pages, and they will load in parallel. After each load completes, using `concat` to add to the *products* array. Note that because they're executed in parallel it assumes that you either don't care about the order, or that the Api responds in the order it received the call.

```js
// took out the axios call 
function getProducts(page) {
  return axios.get("https://my_api_link/products?page=" + page + "&limit=250&access_token=my_access_token", {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.results;
  })
}

var app = new Vue({
  'el': '#myapp',
  data: {
    products: "",
    chosenProduct: null
  },
  created: function() {
    var products = [];
    var numPages = 12;

    for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
      getProducts(1).then(function(results){
        products = products.concat(results)
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }

  }
})
```

As I mentioned, I would likely use something more complex, like vuex to handle when the loading starts and managing the state of download.